# Map through an object with children objects/array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I am trying to map through an array`category`(which is inside an object `List`) and access `id` and `name` which are inside an array of objects.

Below is my data.

```js
List = {
    category: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Alpha',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Bravo',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Charlie',
      },
    ],
  }
```

Below is react  code that is trying to access id and name.

```js
{List.category.map((index, res) => {
                console.log("Output:",res)
              })}

//Output: 0
//Output: 1
//Output: 2
//Output: 0
//Output: 1
//Output: 2
...
```

How can I access `name` and `id` that are inside `category`?

Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. (Although you shouldn't be using `map` if you don't want to render actual output in the UI - but I assume this is just debugging code.)

```
{List.category.map(({ name, id }) => {
  console.log("Output:", name, id);
})}
```

Comment: Thanks, and what should i  do if i want to render  `name` and `id` inside a pragraph
like <p>{name}</p>

Comment: put exactly that to be returned from the `map` function?

Comment: i don't know if i did something wrong but `{List.category.map(({ name, id }) => {
  <p>{name}</p>;
})}` does not render any thing

Comment: because you've not got a `return` statement - although you can do without that if you replace the curly braces by `(...)`